# Deploy react js web app on linux app Service azure

Tags: azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I was deploying a react js website on the Linux app service on Azure. But its not getting deployed on the app service. I have used the pm2 command to run the app on linux environment

> pm2 serve /home/site/wwwroot/ --no-daemon

But in the error logs its giving the error of pm2 not found.And the following one

> Container didn't respond to HTTP pings on port: 8080, failing site start.
>
> Container for site has exited, failing site start

Comment: Do you want to deploy in a production style? You should run `npm run build`. Then copy the built files onto your server.

Comment: Yes i have already run that command in my release build and create a react app build. But at the time of deployment on the azure app service it gives me the error.

Comment: If my reply is helpful, please accept it as answer(click on the mark option beside the reply to toggle it from greyed out to fill in.), see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: Was this issue solved ?

Answer (score 3):

Navigate to the Configuration page of your web app, and add this command to Startup Command :

```
npx serve -s
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Solved Appservice using Linux for react js service with

[image]