# Trying to deploy Angluar web app in Azure Web App service (Linux-based)

Tags: angular, azure, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to deploy my `angular web app` to a `free tier azure web app service` for testing purposes.
My angular app is deployed by an `azure pipeline` and completes successfully.
Which I can confirm in the `Deployment Center` in the azure portal as well.
Though when visiting the page I end up on a 404 page.

As suggested in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72097947/deploying-an-angular-universal-app-in-azure-web-app-service-linux-based) by the second answer.
I added this command to the StartUp section in the configuration

> pm2 serve /home/site/wwwroot --spa --no-daemon

in the logs I can see the following;

```
2024-02-26T12:01:08.928889037Z: [INFO]  12:01:08 0|static-page-server-8080  | [2024-02-26T12:01:08.907Z] Error while serving /home/site/wwwroot/index.html with content-type text/html : ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/site/wwwroot/index.html'
```

Which says it can't find set files. to serve my application.
I, however, don't know where my files would be or how I can find out where azure stores these files so I can adjust the given path for the pm2 command.

Can anyone help with this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to deploy the Angular app successfully you need to build the Angular app in Azure devops pipeline and deploy its dist folder via YAML or Release pipeline. Refer my [SO answer1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76985518/build-and-deployment-of-nodejs-with-angular-using-asude-pipeline-and-appservice/76990599#76990599) and [SO answer2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77846711/deploying-typescript-angular-app-to-azure-app-service-via-azure-devops-pipelin/77858732#77858732) where I have deployed the Angular app via Release and yaml azure devops pipelines.

**`Go to Pipelines > New Pipelines > Azure Repos git > Select your Angular project's repository > Starter pipeline > Add the yaml code below > Replace WebAppName with your Web app> Save and run the pipeline:-`**

***My YAML pipeline code:-***

```yaml
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- task: NodeTool@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '18.x'
  displayName: 'Install Node.js'

- script: |
    npm install
    npm run build
  displayName: 'npm install and build'

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: 'dist'
    ArtifactName: 'dist'
- task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
  displayName: 'Deploy Azure App Service'
  inputs:
    ConnectionType: 'AzureRM'
    azureSubscription: 'SID subscription (0151c365-f598-44d6-b4fd-e2b6e97cb2a7)'
    appType: 'webAppLinux'
    WebAppName: 'siliconwebapp989'
    packageForLinux: 'dist'
    StartupCommand: 'pm2 serve /home/site/wwwroot/my-appangular --no-daemon --spa'
```

***Output:-***

[image]

[image]

*Connected to Azure Repos directly after the deployment in Deployment Center:-*

[image]

Comment: Thank you for you quick and detailed answer. I think through one of your linked posts I found an article you referenced! I will review my build and deploy pipeline against this post and see where I can improve my own solution.

Answer (score 0):

searching for an answer I came upon [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67194441/deploy-react-js-web-app-on-linux-app-service-azure?rq=2).
Though the suggested answer was for a react application.
I tried it myself, by putting the following command in my startup

```
npx serve -s
```

This didn't give me my desired result, BUT it did show my file directories. this allowed me to find my where my index.html was located. In return I could edit the `PM2` command and my application was served as desired. Most like likely there is a different command that doest the same and maybe is even better suited. if so please just comment on my answer improve my answer